# Pressed/Pushed the button

Tags: word-choice, difference

> I went into the elevator and pushed/pressed the button for the fourth floor.

Are these equally natural in this context? Does one of them sound more forceful than the other?

Answer (score 2):

I would personally use *pushed* which sounds more natural.

You actually have to *push* the button i.e. in most cases you can't just touch it (you have to apply force to it) - the button has to physically go in a bit to register the floor you want.

*Pressed* does sound less forceful and I wouldn't use it in this context. I would *press* something on my phone for example. I would use *press* when you just have to touch something, not apply force to it.

Comment: Press: To exert steady weight or **force** against (https://www.thefreedictionary.com/press)

Comment: @MicahWindsor Did I every say it means no force?

Comment: Yes, you did. 'I would use press when you just have to touch something, not apply force to it.'

Answer (score 2):

Both are common, but searching for "`press|push a|the button`" on the GloWBe Web database shows that in North American sources, "press" is somewhat favoured over "push" (US 200:172, CA 54:46) whereas in most other places, "press" is strongly favoured: (UK 299:151; IE 48:25; AU 87:55; IN 54:31; ZA 28:12.) New Zealand is an exception: (29:23).

Answer (score 1):

I would use press the button. Push sounds like you are pushing something away from its current position like on a lever. Press on the other hand is stationary, something that happens in place which is what pressing a button is.

If it is a button on a touch screen, then I would use tap instead.